# Is there a way to keep my Pawn's healing spell?

Tags: dragons-dogma-dark-arisen

My Pawn which I made her I gave her the Vocation of a mage which came with a handy healing spell, she has since mastered that Vocation (I assume because I have all the red wax seals) and I thought of upgrading her to a sorcerer. However when setting her skills she didn't seem to have her healing spell.

I am wondering, is there a way to give her the healing spell as a sorcerer?

Answer (score 1):

No, but you can use other pawns to heal.  You never lose the healing spell, but to use it you must choose your mage.  Its best to level up all skills so you can use the augments from each class to make the perfect pawn.